# Is there a widget for Twitter search?

Tags: app-widgets, search, twitter

I'd like to monitor Twitter for certain keywords.  I wonder if there is a widget which displays live search results on my home screen, which are automaticly updated at a certain interval. I've tried almost every app in the store, but none provides this simple functionality.

Comment: Have you tried Falcon Widget (for Twitter)? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jv.falcon

Comment: @IvanChau It misses that functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the anwer seems to be: "no there isn't", my workaround was to use an RSS-reader widget, and the following RSS URL: `search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=keyword`.

I think its strange I have to go through such hoops, since Twitter provides a HTML-widget for exactly this purpose.  I was expecting at least one Android app to mimic this functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will stop working when [Twitter will retire its old API on June 11, 2013](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates).

Answer (score 4):

There don't seem to be any widgets that let you monitor twitter for certain keywords, but here's a workaround that might do the trick.

Try an application like [Meta widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.metawidget). It can turn any webpage to a widget.

Comment: That's an original work-around, but not really what I'm after. I doubt it will have any transparency for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like that in a widget. However i allways wanted to test this app Falcon Pro (for Twitter), but i don't think you can have a widget, but you can make a search and save it for latter and do not have to retype every time.

Janetter for Twitter has this option of saving searches and notifies you about them, but it doesn't have a widget...

Comment: There is an official HTML widget from Twitter to display searches, so all somebody needs to do is put that code in a Android widget, doesnt seem like rocket-science.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u can try this (TweetCaster for Twitter)   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oYW5kbWFyay50d2VldGNhc3RlciJd